# Parse Local Datastore Network Error 100

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-datastore

I have added the Parse Localdatastore to my app and it is working but before fetching the local results it tries to connect to the network first. It tries to connect then sleeps and tries again multiple times before fetching the local data. Is there a way to stop this and go straight to the local datastore?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're executing a query, you can use [PFQuery#fromLocalDatastore](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)fromLocalDatastore).